# Confused about what Exactly an image feature is

Tags: image-processing, feature-detection, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I read about **image features** on wikipedia and I am still confused about what exactly they are.

Term is explained in a manner such that I cant clear my confusion.

`1. They represent a Class (edge is a feature and boundry is another)`
`2. They represent a instance of a Class(all the edges detected will be a feature)`

Suppose I detect all the corners of an object and put them in an `array` say `A`.
Did I get only one feature or I got `features=len(A)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each feature is an individual "interesting" point or area in the image, with "interesting" depending on what algorithm is used to find features. In your example, you'd have A features, each of the corners being one.